# What IDE to use for Javascript on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ubuntu, ide

I used to develop/debug Javascript on Windows with Visual Studio. Now, I have started working on Ubuntu and I don't feel comfortable with the default editors offered (vim, gedit etc).
Do you have any IDE to propose me ? (Paid license accepted, ideally with jQuery support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's Aptana which is a really good IDE based one but for practical purposes you can always use a lightweight editor such as Emacs, ViM, or even Gedit or nano if you want to keep it simple. For what you're looking for Aptana sounds best.
As another person suggested Webstorm is also quite good (at least I've heard) the company I used to work for used it quite a bit and they loved it so that's worth a try although it is paid of course.

Comment: Sorry , but i have bad souenirs with all folks such as Emacs, Vim, nano etc. It's like , you have to be Geek in mind for using them. I'll give a try to Aptana. Does it support jQuery/jQuery UI ?

Comment: I don't use jquery very often so I'm not sure but Emacs is a great editor :D, can't hate on what's worked for that long.

Comment: When i see Emacs, i have an image in my mind : Richard Stallman with long hair smiling while sitting in front of a computer of the 70's;B/W photo ^^

Comment: I've been using Emacs since I was 12 or 13 and started coding. I'm 20 now and still using it :)

Comment: Wow someone decides to downvote this after it being an answer for months.

Comment: For lightweight, use geany, over gedit, anytime! It is as lightweight, but with a few key features (regex search/replace, navigate code structure, integrated run/build buttons/code folding etc), which make it work so much better as a lightweight IDE replacement!

Answer (score 4):

Aptana, of course: http://www.aptana.com/
Paid license: Webstorm: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: I use WebStorm (and sister products with identical HTML/CSS/JS support PhpStorm, RubyMine and IntelliJ IDEA) and I'm pretty happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would say [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/), it's free and has good autocomplete for jQuery (and YUI). Also, on autocomplete you can see supported browsers for selected methods.

Comment: I don't like Netbeans much. Is it still slow or heavy memory consumption ?

Comment: On my computer (CPU E5500@2.80 Ghz, 4GB RAM) with windows7, netbeans 7.0 is responsive, and it takes cca 400MB of RAM when working with YUI or symfony projects. And I don't have any problems working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Eclipse for JavaScript editor](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosr). Use it with the [colorer plugin](http://eclipsecolorer.sourceforge.net/) (enable the Colorer editor).

Comment: Does Eclipse for Javascript support debugging ?

Comment: I have not tried that yet. I use it as my HTML/CSS/JS editor. There is a SO thread on JavaScript debugging in Eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609316/debug-javascript-in-eclipse). There also seems to some paid native Eclipse Javascript debugging plugin like this one http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?module=htmlpages&func=display&pid=62