# how to debug html file in eclipse?

Tags: android, debugging

I have an android application and I am using javascript in it. Can anyone tell me how can I debug my html files? It doesnt show any option of inserting breakpoints.

Comment: Step one would be to simply run it.

Comment: But I wanana check the values of variables being passed there. I want to debug that file.

Comment: Perhaps check them just before you pass them, or print/alert them.

Comment: Isn't there any way to debug it in Eclipse?

Comment: Try jsHybugger: http://www.jshybugger.org/

It lets you set breakpoints, singlestep, catch exceptions, and interact with the JS/DOM environment. You can use it from Eclipse or from a Chrome or Chrome-compatible debugger on the remote desktop. It can be used with apps that create their own webView.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below in regards to debugging JavaScript in Eclipse.

[Debug JavaScript in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609316/debug-javascript-in-eclipse)

I prefer to debug JS using Firefox addon myself:

http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think eclipse natively offers such feature. However, you may try [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/javascript) plug-in in Mozilla Firefox or [Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156388/how-to-set-breakpoint-in-inline-javascript-in-google-chrome-browser-for-linux) browser (its built-in dev. tools) to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

As the other two answers state; either use the Firebug plugin with Firefox - you can insert breakpoints there, or use Chrome's debugger. It looks a lot like firebug, only it's integrated  with the browser by default.