# Getting Eclipse, Javascript debugging to work

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

I am not able to get Eclipse (luna SR1a) and Javascript debugging with Crossfire to work.
Firefox and Eclipse are definitely connecting. I have Firebug, Crossfire and Status-Ever loaded in Firefox. Am able to start Crossfire listening, and Eclipse Crossfire Debug config in attach mode to connect.
But when starting my html file the webpages work but never break on a breakpoint.
Anyone any suggestions how to fix?

Comment: I second this. I'm running Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), Firebug version 2.0.11, Crossfire 0.3a10 and Status-4-Ever 2015.02.06.23.1-signed. Everything starts up alright Eclipse/Crossfire connect but I'm unable to set breakpoints in Eclipse - they're simply ignored thus rendering the debugging in Eclipse useless. What am I (we) doing wrong here...?