# console.log not working Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, eclipse, console.log

I have searched and searched and am unable to get a simple console.log in javascript or HTML to write to the Eclipse console.

Running the javascript in Google and checking the console works. Just can't figure out how to get it to work in Eclipse.

I am using the following on Mac OS X

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600

Comment: Are you running the html/js in the eclipse browser? I assume it doesn't have support for console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(...)` will write in your browser console. I am not sure the Default Eclipse console has a view for the internal browser it uses. Access your link in a browser like say FireFox and install a plugin called FireBug to see the logs.

There are however many debugging plugins for JavaScript in Eclipse available - have a look here - [Debug JavaScript in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609316/debug-javascript-in-eclipse).

Comment: It could with a potential plugin. Like the console does show server logs, SVN, CVS logs, etc - so it can be extended - just that it isn't built in.