# Can eclipse be used to debug javascript in webpages using the latest Firefox Developer Edition now that firebug and crossfire have been superceeded

Tags: javascript, eclipse, firefox

Using JSDT you used to be able to debug client side javascript in webpages running under firefox using [firebug and crossfire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236810/851774). However firebug is now [deprecated](http://getfirebug.com/). Whilst the new firefox dev tools allow you to debug javascript inside the browser itself, its still useful to have one place to set everything up and also debug server side code (which may be more than just JS). Having tried using the Remote JavaScript Debug configuration in various ways with the latest firefox dev tools [running](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_Desktop)  a debug server, i can only conclude the protocol is now completely diffrent and incompatible with Eclipse Neon  JavaScript Development Tools    2.0.0.v201608301904

Can anyone shed any light on whether this might be supported? Do people just use other IDEs (like Aptana) or the native tools now?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?