# Eclipse debug JavaScript in a Java 2EE project

Tags: eclipse

I'm an italian blind developer.

Actually i use Eclipse IDE for a Java J2EE project. In this project there are a web app with JavaScript and a lot of WSDL.

For debug and run the web app layer I run out of Eclipse my Tomcat Application Server, after I attach Eclipse Debug on this Tomcat. All works fine!

For debug JavaScript the most all developer user the integrated tools in Firefox or Chrome. This tools aren't accessibile with the assistive technology for blind, I use NVDA and JAWS.

Eclipse IDE is accessibile and i think to attach the JavaScript debugger in this IDE.

Is possible?
Any alternative ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug JavaScript in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609316/debug-javascript-in-eclipse)

Comment: Hi! in these months, I read many posts on internet,no one has answered completely to my questions. I have read that there is a debugger called RINO, do you know how to configure it in Eclipse and in the server? Is there a way to debug javascript directly from eclipse? Thanks!