# Client-Side Code Debugging Javascript in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, client, frontend

I want to debug client-side javascript in the Eclipse ide.

I know, this is possible with browsers like Firefox or Chrome, but I wish to have this in a window
within the IDE.

There are any solutions to connect a Chrome or Firefox browser with Eclipse using Chrome Tools or
CrossFire, but I found out, these solutions are outdated.

I also found this description
at Stackoverflow [Debug JavaScript in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609316/debug-javascript-in-eclipse)
 to do this, but unfortunately all of them are outdated.
 Either the plugins are quite old or the links do not work anymore.

However, there are other solutions like PhpStorm to do this, but these are not available for free.

Are there any ways to debug client-side javascript in Eclipse ?
Is there a plugin available ?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say, "window within the IDE", do you mean the code or the application as well (browser tab within Eclipse)?

Comment: Yes I mean, the code is in an editor within Eclipse and I can set breakpoints. Then I start the app in a browser (maybe external firefox) and I can debug them within Eclipse (stops at breakpoint, view variable values).

Comment: Tom, you should be able to do this with CodeMix from Genuitec, though we only support external Chrome debugging for now. We also have some Live Preview functionality that you may find interesting.